# Redrawing UITextView selection after changing paragraph style

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

As a preliminary stage to an app I want to make, I've set up a simple test example of indenting the paragraphs in a `UITextView`. It basically sets up an `NSTextStorage` with some text and puts it in a text view. When the user taps an indent button, I want the paragraph(s) that overlap the current selection to indent.

The part that *doesn't* work is that after the paragraph is indented, the blue selection highlight stays in that location and doesn't move to where the text that was selected is now located. What am I missing to make this refresh happen?

Here's what the working part before the indent looks like:

[image: an image showing the selected text in the text view]

And here's what the same selection looks like after the indent:

[image]

The code for the indention:

```
UITextRange *startRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:[textView selectedTextRange].start withGranularity:UITextGranularityParagraph inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionForward];
UITextRange *endRange = [textView.tokenizer rangeEnclosingPosition:[textView selectedTextRange].end withGranularity:UITextGranularityParagraph inDirection:UITextStorageDirectionBackward];
NSInteger startOffset = MIN([textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:startRange.start], [textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:endRange.start]);
NSInteger endOffset = MAX([textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:endRange.end], [textView offsetFromPosition:textView.beginningOfDocument toPosition:startRange.end]);
NSRange offsetRange = NSMakeRange(startOffset, endOffset - startOffset);

[self.textStorage beginEditing];
[self.textStorage enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                             inRange:offsetRange
                             options:0
                          usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
                              ((NSMutableParagraphStyle *)value).firstLineHeadIndent += [self tabIndent];
                              ((NSMutableParagraphStyle *)value).headIndent += [self tabIndent];
                              [self.textStorage removeAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName range:range];
                              [self.textStorage addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:value range:range];
                          }];
[self.textStorage endEditing];
```

Maybe this is a silly question, but I'd appreciate an outside eye. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit late, but maybe it helps you or others....

You can change the selection through the [UITextInput-Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInput/selectedTextRange) by setting the selectedTextRange .

```
let beginning: UITextPosition = textView.beginningOfDocument
let start: UITextPosition = textView.positionFromPosition(beginning, offset: textView.selectedRange.location)
let end: UITextPosition = textView.positionFromPosition(start!, offset: textView.selectedRange.length)

textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRangeFromPosition(start!, toPosition: end!)
```

P.S. My code is written in Swift, but I think it is no problem to convert that to objective c, or?

Comment: This code by itself didn't work, but I tried it and added `textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)` (in Objective-C) before the last line and it did work then. I think the text view needed to have the selected range changed somehow in order to refresh. Thanks so much for providing this solution! If you'll just add that line into your code snippet I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I'm glad that I can help you :) Added your code line to the snippet ;)